# Track ad Conversions with Clickfunnels and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, ads

1. We would like to advertise on Social Media (Facebook, LinkedIn,  ..).
2. In the ads we link to a Clickfunnel Webinar Page.
3. The Webinar has a contact form that sends us an E-Mail.

I would like to track conversions from the different ads using Google Analytics.
I struggle how to correctly integrate GA.

So far I have figured out that, in the ads we need to use URL parameters linking to the Clickfunnel to figure out which ad is generating the most leads. (utmsource=linkedin, ..)
I have embedded the GA Tracking Code into my clickfunnels page. Which tracks good so far, but of course I cannot see the sources right now.

How do I track the conversions to see which ads generate the most sent contact forms?